# Use attributes to segment data using XmlReader

Tags: xml

I'm using an XML file along with XmlReader to populate a class object.

Here's my class object:

```
public class WikiMeta
{
    string _subject;

    public List<WikiArticle> Articles = new List<WikiArticle>();

    public List<WikiGroup> Groups = new List<WikiGroup>();

    public string PageMetaDescription { get; set; }

    public string PageTitle { get; set; }

    public string Route { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a sample of XML:

```
<AllMeta>
  <WikiMeta>
    <Subject>The Subject</Subject>
    <PageTitle>Page title</PageTitle>
    <PageMetaDescription>Page meta description</PageMetaDescription>
    <Articles>
      <WikiArticle>
        <FileName>file.txt</FileName>
      </WikiArticle>
    </Articles>
    <Groups>
      <WikiGroup>
        <Name>Main group</Name>
      </WikiGroup>
      <WikiGroup>
        <Name>Secondary group</Name>
      </WikiGroup>
    </Groups>
  </WikiMeta>
</AllMeta>
```

Using the XmlReader class, the XML is automatically mapped to my class properties, however, I now want to introduce variations on the article type. The 2 obvious solutions to me are:

1. Replace WikiGroup with 2 new groups PeerGroup and ChildGroup
2. Add a Type element inside WikiGroup

However, I wondered if there was a way of adding an attribute to WikiGroup and mapping it to two different properties in my class, something like this:

```
WikiGroup attr="peer">
        <Name>Main group</Name>
      </WikiGroup>

[XmlAttribute("peer")]
public WikiGroup PeerGroup { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("child")]
public WikiGroup ChildGroup { get; set; }
```

I don't know if this is possible or not, but any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you would like to have:

```
<Groups>
  <WikiGroup type="peer">
    <Name>Main group</Name>
  </WikiGroup>
  <WikiGroup type="child">
    <Name>Secondary group</Name>
  </WikiGroup>
</Groups>
```

You should add the `Type` property to your `WikiGroup` class, as you already stated:

```
public partial class WikiGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

In the `WikiMeta` class, you may add 2 properties:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public WikiGroup PeerGroup
{
    get
    {
        return groupsField.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Type== "peer");
    }
    set
    {
        if (groupsField == null)
            groupsField = new List<WikiGroup>();
        var peerGroup = groupsField.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Type == "peer");
        if (peerGroup != null)
            groupsField.Remove(peerGroup);
        value.Type = "peer";
        groupsField.Add(value);
    }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public WikiGroup ChildGroup
{
    get
    {
        return groupsField.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Type == "child");
    }
    set
    {
        if (groupsField == null)
            groupsField = new List<WikiGroup>();
        var childGroup = groupsField.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Type == "child");
        if (childGroup != null)
            groupsField.Remove(childGroup);
        value.Type = "child";
        groupsField.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Besides the newly added properties, you have to take care of the `Groups` setter:

```
private List<WikiGroup> groupsField;

public List<WikiGroup> Groups
{
    get
    {
        return this.groupsField;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Type == "peer") == null && PeerGroup != null)
            value.Add(PeerGroup);
        if (value.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Type == "child") == null && ChildGroup != null)
            value.Add(ChildGroup);
        this.groupsField = value;
    }
}
```

This has to be done in order to prevent the overriding of the values in a similar to the below object creation:

```
WikiMeta o = new WikiMeta()
{
    PeerGroup = new WikiGroup() { Name = "Test Peer" },
    ChildGroup = new WikiGroup() { Name = "Test Child" },
    Groups = new List<WikiGroup>()
};
```